# I'm trying to add data which have same value in sql. How can I do that?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE DON
(
    REGI_NUM INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    MAKE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    MODEL VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    TYPE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CATEGORY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DAILY_RENTAL_RATE INTEGER NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(REGI_NUM)
);

INSERT INTO CAR
VALUES (**389238**,'TOYOTA','FJ cruise','sedan','luxury',49);
```

In this data and following data have same REGI_NUM. when I add them in tera term VT, it said unique constraint violated. How can I add them?

```
INSERT INTO CAR
VALUES (**389238**, 'MITSUBISHI', 'cruise', 'hatchback', 'luxury', 67);

INSERT INTO CAR
VALUES (326372, 'TOYOTA', 'MDX', 'sedan', 'normal', 20);

INSERT INTO CAR
VALUES (324244, 'Acura', 'FJ cruise', 'SUV', 'luxury', 57);

INSERT INTO CAR
VALUES (124345, 'Acura', 'TL 4dr', 'sedan', 'normal', 23);

INSERT INTO CAR
VALUES (326372, 'Aucara', 'D345', 'sedan', 'luxury', 49);

INSERT INTO CAR
VALUES (389238, 'TOYOTA', 'FJ cruise', 'sedan', 'normal', 24);

INSERT INTO CAR
VALUES (324244, 'Honda', 'odyseey', 'sedan', 'luxury', 57);
```

### Update

Sorry it needs to be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE DON
(REGI_NUM INTEGER NOT NULL,
MAKE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
MODEL VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
TYPE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CATEGORY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
DAILY_RENTAL_RATE INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(REGI_NUM));

INSERT INTO CAR
VALUES (389238,'TOYOTA','FJ cruise','sedan','luxury',49);
INSERT INTO CAR
VALUES (389238,'MITSUBISHI','cruise','hatchback','luxury',67);
INSERT INTO CAR
VALUES (326372,'TOYOTA','MDX','sedan','normal',20);
INSERT INTO CAR
VALUES (324244,'Acura','FJ cruise','SUV','luxury',57);
INSERT INTO CAR
VALUES (124345,'Acura','TL 4dr','sedan','normal',23);
INSERT INTO CAR
VALUES (326372,'Aucara','D345','sedan','luxury',49);
INSERT INTO CAR
VALUES (389238,'TOYOTA','FJ cruise','sedan','normal',24);
INSERT INTO CAR
VALUES (324244,'Honda','odyseey','sedan','luxury',57);
```

Comment: You're inserting the same [primary key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key) twice. They have to be unique.

Comment: You need a different primary key. If the registration numbers can be the same (which seems odd) then you need to add a unique key - like a record_id that is never duplicated.

Comment: @Robby @ daShier thanks, guys. Can you check the code below?

Comment: You should have updated your question instead of writing an answer. Anyway, doesn't change anything. You're still inserting a duplicate primary key.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen sorry, I'm new to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`PRIMARY KEY(REGI_NUM))`

Since `REGI_NUM` is the primary key every entry for that column should be unique and not null.

If you want to repeat values, create a table without a primary key on `REGI_NUM` and add another column to have unique/not null values for primary key if there is a purpose.

Comment: I'll try to do that.